# On running this python code in GOOGLE COLAB, it showing me error. Can anyone please tell what am i doing wrong and share a corrected code?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, finance

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

stock = ['AAPL']

data = web.DataReader(stock,data_source="yahoo",start='01/01/2010')['Adj Close']
data.sort_index(inplace=True)

returns = data.pct_change()
mean_return = returns.mean()

return_stdev = returns.std()
annualised_return = round(mean_return * 252,2)

annualised_stdev = round(return_stdev * np.sqrt(252),2)

print ('The annualised mean return of stock {} is {}, ' 
        'and the annualised volatility is {}').format(stock[0],annualised_return,annualised_stdev)
```

Comment: I am using python for a finance assignment. https://pythonforfinance.net/2017/01/21/investment-portfolio-optimisation-with-python/ . you can find the above code here .

Comment: Please share the details regarding the error occurred.

Comment: “*it showing me error.*” How can we possibly help you if you haven’t included the exact text of the error? [ask]

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: I looked into the code here and from the article mentioned and I found that the last print statement has an issue with the `.format` being outside the print function. If that is the error then the fix would be very simple by removing the `)` before `.format` and adding it at the end of `print` function.

Comment: when you click on that link pythonforfinance, You'll find a python code. the same code, when put in Google Colab,didnt work as expected.  @kite **correct it and make it work in colab & share**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release notes for [pandas_datareader 0.10.0](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/releases/tag/v0.10.0) does mention that there were issues with **Yahoo API's** requiring headers and were fixed in this release (0.10.0).

> Fixed Yahoo readers which now require headers

So, if your `google-colab` uses any version older than 0.10.0 will have problems using **Yahoo API's**. 

Here are some steps on how to debug the issue in `google-colab` - `jupyter notebook`. 
**Step 1: Determine the installed version of module `pandas_datareader`.**

```
!pip show pandas_datareader
```

**Step 2: if the version is lower than 0.10.0 then upgrade the version.**

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas_datareader
```

**Step 3: Don't forget to restart the runtime to load the new libraries.**

```
Press Runtime->Restart runtime
```

**Step 4: Now try running the step 1 again to determine if the newest version is installed.**

```
!pip show pandas_datareader
```

I hope the newest version will be installed and you can run your above code with the correction mentioned by @[Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3220135/aaron) in his answer. 

Note: `!` is required before shell commands. Try going thorugh [the official docs of IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#system-shell-commands) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `format` on the output of the `print` function by putting it after the close parenthesis. `print` doesn't return anything, so you're effectively calling `None.format(...)` (which doesn't exist). You should instead call format on the string directly as such:

```py
print('The annualised mean return of stock {} is {}, and the annualised volatility is {}'.format(stock[0],annualised_return,annualised_stdev))
```

Comment: SHOWING ERROR: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py:272: SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'AAPL', replacing with NaN.
  warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f7cf256af978> in <module>()
      5 stock = ['AAPL']
      6 
----> 7 data = web.DataReader(stock,data_source="yahoo",start='01/01/2010')['Adj Close']
      8 data.sort_index(inplace=True)

Comment: @Vector you need to edit your question, and post the entire traceback. This is just the first few lines, which does not give the error location. I suspect `pandas_datareader` is not up-to-date with the latest version. otherwise making this single edit makes the code work just fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

import numpy as np 

import pandas as pd

stock = ['AAPL']

data = web.DataReader(stock,data_source="yahoo",start='01/01/2010')['Adj Close'] 
data.sort_index(inplace=True)

returns = data.pct_change() 

mean_return = returns.mean()

return_stdev = returns.std() 

annualised_return = round(mean_return * 252,2)

annualised_stdev = round(return_stdev * np.sqrt(252),2)

print(f"The annualised mean return of stock {stock[0]} is {annualised_return}, and the annualised volatility is {annualised_stdev}")
```

So the error came because you did not use a f string. An f string puts data in-between the brackets{}

> For more info visit:
> [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-output-formatting/#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20there%20is%20no%20printf%20%28%29%20function,string%20modulo%20%28or%20sometimes%20even%20called%20modulus%29%20operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-output-formatting/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20there%20is%20no%20printf%20%28%29%20function,string%20modulo%20%28or%20sometimes%20even%20called%20modulus%29%20operator).

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py:272: SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'AAPL', replacing with NaN.
  warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-49637de5b83b> in <module>()
      7 stock = ['AAPL']
      8 
----> 9 data = web.DataReader(stock,data_source="yahoo",start='01/01/2010')['Adj Close']
     10 data.sort_index(inplace=True)
     11

Comment: this is wht im getting after run this in google colab . please share something that works in google colab.